# Move cursor by line number when moving through multiple lines (e.g. `5j`), move by display line when moving through a single line (e.g. `j`)

Tags: vim, vimrc

In Vim, I have the following set in order to have ragged right soft-wrapping of lines:

```
set linebreak
set wrap
```

When traversing multiple lines at once, an annoying side effect is that `5j` will not move the cursor down 5 lines, it will move it down by 5 display lines. If I have a line that is soft-wrapped into 6 lines, if my cursor is on the top line and I type `5j` I will not move down by 5 actual lines, but rather to the bottom of the current line, down by 5 display lines.

**How can I stop this behaviour so that `j` moves the cursor down by 1 display line (soft-wrapped or otherwise), while `5j` moves the cursor down by 5 actual lines?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default the `j` and `k` movements always move by physical lines and not by screen lines. So I think you must have a map like `nmap j gj` somewhere in your .vimrc.

For the behaviour you want, I have the following in my .vimrc:

```
" Map j and k to gj/gk, but only when no count is given
" However, for larger jumps like 6j add the current position to the jump list
" so that you can use <c-o>/<c-i> to jump to the previous position
nnoremap <expr> j v:count ? (v:count > 5 ? "m'" . v:count : '') . 'j' : 'gj'
nnoremap <expr> k v:count ? (v:count > 5 ? "m'" . v:count : '') . 'k' : 'gk'
```